# Infinite Geometric Series in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to re-create an app in C# based on Cookie Clickers for my college work. What I'm currently trying to do is have it so when I press the upgrade button on my application, it will work like Cookie Clicker where it firstly increases by 2 and after 3 clicks of that button it will then double from 2 to 4 and keep doing that. I've currently got this but for some reason it's just a fixed number of '15' and doesn't increase at all. Now I don't fully understand how this method works but I was also hoping someone could elaborate it for me.

Here's the function:

```
    static double GeometricSeries(double a, double r, int n)
    {
        return a * (1 - Math.Pow(r, n + 1)) / (1 - r);
    }
```

Here's how I've executed the function:

```
    double x = GeometricSeries(1, 2, 3);
    GV.CpsCostAmount = x;
```

(EXAMPLE)
To elaborate on my question, I want to know how I can change this so that for every certain amount of times that you upgrade, it will increase the price by x amount and after x amount upgrades it increase it. It's quite hard to explain in words what I mean but the best way you'll understand what I mean is if you see the game.

Upgrade button function:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double a = 2;
        double r = 3;
        int n = 4;
        double x = GeometricSeries(a, r, n);
        GV.CpsCostAmount = x;

        //Finder
        if (GV.TotalMoneyValue < GV.CpsCostAmount)
        {
            //Return Error
            tmrErrorShow.Enabled = true;
            lblErrorMessage.Text = "You don't have enough money for that.";
            return;
        }
        else if (GV.TotalMoneyValue >= GV.CpsCostAmount)
        {
            //Minus Money
            int ToDecreaseBy = Convert.ToInt32(GV.CpsCostAmount);
            GV.TotalMoneyValue -= ToDecreaseBy;
            lblMoney.Text = string.Format("{0}{1:#,0}", GV.MoneyPrefix, GV.TotalMoneyValue);

            //Update Button Text
            btnUpgradeCps.Text = string.Format("{0}{1}", GV.UpgradeCpsPrefix, GV.CpsCostAmount);

            //Increase CPS
            int ToIncreaseBy = GV.TotalCPSValue += GV.CPSIncrease;
            lblClicksPerSecond.Text = string.Format("{0}{1:#,#}", GV.CpsPrefix, GV.TotalCPSValue);

            //Check Total Damage and set
            int TotalDamage = GV.TotalDPSValue + GV.TotalCPSValue;
            lblTotalDamage.Text = string.Format("{0}{1:#,#}", GV.TotalPrefix, TotalDamage);
        }
        else
        {
            tmrErrorShow.Enabled = true;
            lblErrorMessage.Text = "Something went quite very wrong.";
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear what actually is being asked. Could you please narrow the context a bit and describe the difference between expected and actual behaviour for a specific example?

Comment: If you want different output you will need to give the method different input, repeatedly calling the method with the values 1,2 and 3 will give you the same result every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers 1, 2 and 3 are something called 'literals', which means that the method GeometricSeries will always receive these numbers as input.
In order to make the mehod give a different result than 15 you need to pass variables to the method instead, and somehow change these variables whenever you click the upgrade button.

```
double a = 1;
double r = 2;
int n = 3

double x = GeometricSeries(a, r, n);
```

Now, if you modify the variables a, r or n, the method will return a different value.

EDIT: Try to declare the three variables outside the method instead, and only increment them whenever you click the button. Declaring the variables inside the method will make the method always use the same numbers whenever the button is clicked, thus the variables need to be declared outside, only using the method to increase them.

```
double a = 2;
double r = 3;
int n = 4;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    n++; // For instance

    double x = GeometricSeries(a, r, n);
    GV.CpsCostAmount = x;

    //The rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: I did that but it still stays at 15 and doesn't increase.

Comment: Try: double a = 2;
double r = 3;
int n = 4

Comment: @SirTiggs, Copying the code above will give you the same values, you need to change the values assigned to a, r and n each time the button is clicked.

Comment: @BenRobinson Here's what I've got currently.                       **double a = 2;
            double r = 3;
            int n = 4;

            double x = GeometricSeries(a, r, n);
            GV.CpsCostAmount = x;**

Comment: GeometricSeries(1, 2, 3) is not equal to GeometricSeries(2, 3, 4). If your result is 15 no matter what, then the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @SirTiggs Pass a diferent value for n each time the button is clicked and you will get a geometrically increasing result, but if you alwys pass the same values, you will always get the same answer. e.g. a + b  = c, if a and b are always the same then c will always be the same.

Comment: @Godspark Oh no it's something like 254 now but it still doesn't increase.

Comment: OK, so it is some text that is not updating correctly? Would you kindly provide the code for displaying the value?

Comment: @BenRobinson Ahh I see what you mean. Is there any chance you could give me an example of how I could change the values each time, just so I fully understand.

Comment: @Godspark **btnUpgradeCps.Text = string.Format("{0}{1}", GV.UpgradeCpsPrefix, GV.CpsCostAmount);**

Comment: @SirTiggs Looks ok. But what is the code that is executed whenever you click the upgrade button?

Comment: @Godspark I'll put it in the top section for you.

Comment: @SirTiggs You can edit your original post, and all lines that have at least four spaces in front of it will be in code format.

Comment: @Godspark Ohhh my, it's truly the simplest things that get me. That works VERY well thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: @SirTiggs Yes, often it is the simple things that are unspotted. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what Cookie Clickers is.

"it firstly increases by 2 and after 3 clicks of that button it will then double from 2 to 4 and keep doing that"

If you want the cost to double every three clicks why not do this?

```
int numClicks=0;
void OnUpgrade()
{
    numClicks++;
    if (numClicks == 3)
    {
        GV.CpsCostAmount = GV.CpsCostAmount * 2;
        numClicks = 0;
    }
}
```